# How can I find the overlap of these two objects that have a string and array for properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, compare

I have two objects that represent baseball players and I want to see if they ever played on the same team. There is a team object for each team they played for with properties of name and array of years they played on that team. I want to compare two objects of that to see if there is overlap.

```
{
    "_id": "/players/h/hunteto01.shtml",
    "url": "/players/h/hunteto01.shtml",
    "name": "Torii Hunter",
    "image": "https://www.baseball-reference.com/req/202108020/images/headshots/7/79f9873b_br.jpg",
    "teams": [{
        "name": "MIN",
        "years": [1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2015]
    }, {
        "name": "LAA",
        "years": [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012]
    }, {
        "name": "DET",
        "years": [2013, 2014]
    }],
    "searchName": "torii hunter"
}

{
    "_id": "/players/m/mauerjo01.shtml",
    "url": "/players/m/mauerjo01.shtml",
    "name": "Joe Mauer",
    "image": "https://www.baseball-reference.com/req/202108020/images/headshots/4/43c69595_mlbam.jpg",
    "teams": [{
        "name": "MIN",
        "years": [2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
    }],
    "searchName": "joe mauer"
}
```

The overlap occurs at `MIN 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2015` I just need to return a boolean I don't actually need the values or anything. How can I accomplish this in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```js
const playerOne = {
  _id: "/players/h/hunteto01.shtml",
  url: "/players/h/hunteto01.shtml",
  name: "Torii Hunter",
  image:
    "https://www.baseball-reference.com/req/202108020/images/headshots/7/79f9873b_br.jpg",
  teams: [
    {
      name: "MIN",
      years: [
        1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2015,
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "LAA",
      years: [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012],
    },
    {
      name: "DET",
      years: [2013, 2014],
    },
  ],
  searchName: "torii hunter",
};

const playerTwo = {
  _id: "/players/m/mauerjo01.shtml",
  url: "/players/m/mauerjo01.shtml",
  name: "Joe Mauer",
  image:
    "https://www.baseball-reference.com/req/202108020/images/headshots/4/43c69595_mlbam.jpg",
  teams: [
    {
      name: "MIN",
      years: [
        2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015,
        2016, 2017, 2018,
      ],
    },
  ],
  searchName: "joe mauer",
};

/**
 * This returns a boolean value if two players have played on the same team in the same year
 * @param playerOne
 * @param playerTwo
 * @returns boolean
 **/
function sameTeamSameYear(playerOne, playerTwo) {
  const playerOneTeams = playerOne.teams;
  const playerTwoTeams = playerTwo.teams;

  for (const playerOneTeam of playerOneTeams) {
    for (const playerTwoTeam of playerTwoTeams) {
      if (playerOneTeam.name === playerTwoTeam.name) {
        for (const playerOneYear of playerOneTeam.years) {
          for (const playerTwoYear of playerTwoTeam.years) {
            if (playerOneYear === playerTwoYear) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(sameTeamSameYear(playerOne, playerTwo));
```

Or if you prefer a possibly a cleaner approach you could also do this:

```js
const playerOne = {
  _id: "/players/h/hunteto01.shtml",
  url: "/players/h/hunteto01.shtml",
  name: "Torii Hunter",
  image:
    "https://www.baseball-reference.com/req/202108020/images/headshots/7/79f9873b_br.jpg",
  teams: [
    {
      name: "MIN",
      years: [
        1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2015,
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "LAA",
      years: [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012],
    },
    {
      name: "DET",
      years: [2013, 2014],
    },
  ],
  searchName: "torii hunter",
};

const playerTwo = {
  _id: "/players/m/mauerjo01.shtml",
  url: "/players/m/mauerjo01.shtml",
  name: "Joe Mauer",
  image:
    "https://www.baseball-reference.com/req/202108020/images/headshots/4/43c69595_mlbam.jpg",
  teams: [
    {
      name: "MIN",
      years: [
        2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015,
        2016, 2017, 2018,
      ],
    },
  ],
  searchName: "joe mauer",
};

/**
 * This returns a boolean value if two players have played on the same team in the same year (possibly a cleaner approach)
 * @param playerOne
 * @param playerTwo
 * @returns boolean
 **/
function sameTeamSameYear(playerOne, playerTwo) {
  const playerOneTeams = playerOne.teams.map((team) => team.name);
  const playerTwoTeams = playerTwo.teams.map((team) => team.name);

  const playerOneYears = playerOne.teams.reduce((acc, team) => {
    return [...acc, ...team.years];
  }, []);

  const playerTwoYears = playerTwo.teams.reduce((acc, team) => {
    return [...acc, ...team.years];
  }, []);

  const sameTeam = playerOneTeams.some((team) => playerTwoTeams.includes(team));
  const sameYear = playerOneYears.some((year) => playerTwoYears.includes(year));

  return sameTeam && sameYear;
}

console.log(sameTeamSameYear(playerOne, playerTwo));
```